# Convert Object properties into their own objects possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I'm pulling some JSON data:

```
[{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}]
```

Is it possible to convert the above to:

```
[{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}, {"c": "3"}]
```

How can this be achieved in JS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware that object properties in JavaScript don't have order, so your array may have values sorted randomly.

Comment: I tried looping via a forEach statement and pushing into an empty {}, although it just dumps all the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the object keys and loop over the objects with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var newArr = Object.keys(arr[0]).map(function (key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = arr[0][key];
  return obj;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jya7ypb3/)

Comment: I always forget about `Object.keys()`, dangit :P Side-note: `map` is IE 9+

Comment: I think with `Object.keys` you don't need to use `hasOwnProperty` either.

Comment: Still, it's nice to know more about how hasOwnProperty works!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

```
var myObj = [{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}];
```

Then, you can do this:

```
var result = []; // output array
for(key in myObj[0]){ // loop through the object
    if(myObj[0].hasOwnProperty(key)){ // if the current key isn't a prototype property
        var temp = {};               // create a temp object
        temp[key] = myObj[0][key];  // Assign the value to the temp object
        result.push(temp);         // And add the object to the output array
    }
}

console.log(result);
// [{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}, {"c": "3"}]
```